# Reducing the height of the Edit Text in Android-Not Working

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi i used this code in xml file i am trying to reduce the height of the edit text i changed the android:height="" value but nothing happened in edit text.Please help

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:ems="4"
    android:maxEms="4"
    android:height="3dp"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:width="200dp" >
```

```
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout_height is already wrap_content.
Do something like:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="3dp"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
android:ems="4"
android:maxEms="4"
android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
```

Ignore extra values.

Answer (score 0):

You should play with layout_height attribute :

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="3dp"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
android:ems="4"
android:maxEms="4"
android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>
```

But not all layouts let view resize this way.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using wr`ap_content` as the value for the layout_height

you should write a value for  example :

```
10dp , 12dp , etc .
```

that suits your needs 
the `wrap_content` , wraps your editText to fit the text that is in it .

Hope that helps .